# Autosubmit Form Not Working

Tags: javascript, php

I've seen other posts about this. Mine problem is that I am trying to make this work inside php. I'm not sure what I did wrong. The messagebox appears but when I press 'ok' it didn't submit the form at all...

```
<?php
function loadlogin($varxac, $varxpi){
    echo'<form style="visibility:hidden;" name="loginner" id="loginner"     action="..'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?module=loadlogin" method="POST">';
    echo'<input type="hidden" name="sac" id="sac" maxlength="32" value="'.$varxac.'"/>';
    echo'<input type="hidden" name="spn" id="spn" maxlength="32" value="'.$varxpi.'"/>';
    echo'<input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden;" value="submit" id="submit">';
    echo'</form>';
    //Loginner Script
    echo'
<script>
var auto_refresh = setTimeout(function() { submitform(); }, 10000);

function submitform()
{
  alert(\'test\');
  document.getElementById("loginner").submit();
}
</script>
    ';
    //Login Style
    echo 'Please wait as we login your account';
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance to those who will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
document.loginner.submit();
```

Code:

```
<?php
        function loadlogin($varxac, $varxpi){
            echo'<form  name="loginner" id="loginner"     action="..'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?module=loadlogin" method="POST">';
            echo'<input type="hidden" name="sac" id="sac" maxlength="32" value="'.$varxac.'"/>';
            echo'<input type="hidden" name="spn" id="spn" maxlength="32" value="'.$varxpi.'"/>';                
            echo'</form>';
            //Loginner Script
            echo'
                <script>    
                    function submitform()
                    {
                      alert(\'test\');
                     window.loginner.submit();
                    }
                    // submitform();
                    var auto_refresh = setTimeout(function() { submitform(); }, 10000);
                </script>
            ';
            //Login Style
            echo 'Please wait as we login your account';
        }

        loadlogin($varxac, $varxpi);// need to replace your values $varxac, $varxpi
?>
```

Comment: the function was being executed on the main php file so this php was being attached there through 'require_once'.

Comment: I have tested this, it is working in my instance. Please check my updated answer

Comment: i want to set a timeout for this. where will i place the setTimeout() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.forms["loginner"].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of the other solutions posted here will work for you. `document.getElementById("loginner")` will return you a DOM node, not a Form object, which is why your code doesn't work as intended.

Comment: So i want it to proceed with the action link then. Any suggestion?